# App.post req.body object is appearing empty

Tags: javascript, json

I'm sending a JSON object via axios.post to my servers endpoint and the data seems to console as empty even though within my axios it consoles correctly.

My Frontend is running at port:3000 and my server port:3400.

My axios post:

```
  getRefundCalc(props) {
console.log('the props of the card, are they different for each card?' + JSON.stringify(props))

var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'

}
axios.post(`http://localhost:3400/refundCalc`, props, { headers: headers })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('props within axios ++++++++++++++++++ 2' + JSON.stringify(props))

  })
}
```

The console works fine with 'props', I'll add the object itself at the end.
This is my app.post:

```
app.post('/refundCalc', function (req, res) {
  console.log('response from client - get refund request ' + JSON.stringify(req.body))
  console.log('request from client - get refund request ' + req.body)
})
```

The set up of my server looks like this:

```
let multer = require('multer');
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

This is the response I get from my app.post endpoint:

```
response from client - get refund request {}
request from client - get refund request [object Object]
```

There aren't any errors on my front-end side or even server side. As you can see when I stringify the request it just comes up empty!

The data I am trying to send is in this format:

```
{
"data": {
    "items": {
        "id": 1580841107519,
        "variant_id": 7051095179327,
        "title": "Fashion Summer Floral Print Dress",
        "name": "Fashion Summer Floral Print Dress - Black / L",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": "16.76",
        "product_id": 561553145919
    },
    "imageLinks": {
        "product_id": 561553145919,
        "image_src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0013/6688/4415/products/product-image-308841702.jpg?v=1521568884",
        "varrient_id": [7051095179327, 7051095212095, 7051095244863, 7051095277631]
    },
    "id": 0
},
"classes": {
    "card": "MediaCard-card-1",
    "media": "MediaCard-media-2"
}
}
```

My expected result is that I can console my data on my servers endpoint end So I know im successfully receiving it and can use it, thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: have you added body-parser(https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) in your express server?

Comment: I am using this:     const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are sending the body in JSON format, you need to use JSON parser in the server side to parse the body. You will need to add this line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Yay thank you :) Also thank you to William Chong the commenter who also led me to understand bodyParser which resulted in me finding this answer too!